# CRNN model for word data not learning anything after 10 epochs on 932 train images

Tags: python, neural-network, conv-neural-network, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to predict words from images of Bangla words using CRNN approach. I am training it in a local environment with 932 images and 10 epochs. The loss is decreasing but accuracy is 0% . The model is kinda doing random guessing , and not learning anything . Following is my model :

```
import torch.nn as nn


class BidirectionalLSTM(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, number_of_input, number_of_hidden, nunmer_of_out):
        super(BidirectionalLSTM, self).__init__()

        self.rnn = nn.LSTM(number_of_input, number_of_hidden, bidirectional=True)
        self.embedding = nn.Linear(number_of_hidden * 2, nunmer_of_out)

    def forward(self, input):
        recurrent, _ = self.rnn(input)
        T, b, h = recurrent.size()
        # print("size from recurrent forward :{} {} {}".format(T,b,h))
        t_rec = recurrent.view(T * b, h)
        # print("size after recurrent view : {}".format(t_rec.size()))
        output = self.embedding(t_rec)  # [T * b, nOut]

        output = output.view(T, b, -1)
        return output


class CRNN(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, imgH, nc, nclass, nh, n_rnn=2, leakyRelu=False):
        super(CRNN, self).__init__()
        # assert imgH % 16 == 0, 'imgH has to be a multiple of 16'

        ks = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2]  # original [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2]
        ps = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
        ss = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
        nm = [64, 128, 256, 256, 512, 512, 512]

        cnn = nn.Sequential()

        def conv_relu(i, batchNormalization=False):
            nIn = nc if i == 0 else nm[i - 1]
            nOut = nm[i]
            cnn.add_module('conv{0}'.format(i),
                           nn.Conv2d(nIn, nOut, ks[i], ss[i], ps[i]))
            if batchNormalization:
                cnn.add_module('batchnorm{0}'.format(i), nn.BatchNorm2d(nOut))
            if leakyRelu:
                cnn.add_module('relu{0}'.format(i),
                               nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True))
            else:
                cnn.add_module('relu{0}'.format(i), nn.ReLU(True))

        conv_relu(0)
        cnn.add_module('pooling{0}'.format(0), nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2))  # 64x16x64 original
        conv_relu(1)
        cnn.add_module('pooling{0}'.format(1), nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2))  # 128x8x32 original
        conv_relu(2, True)
        conv_relu(3)
        cnn.add_module('pooling{0}'.format(2),
                       nn.MaxPool2d((2, 2), (2, 1), (0, 1)))  # 256x4x16 original
        conv_relu(4, True)
        conv_relu(5)
        cnn.add_module('pooling{0}'.format(3),
                       nn.MaxPool2d((2, 2), (2, 1), (0, 1)))  # 512x2x16 original
        conv_relu(6, True)  # 512x1x16
        # Extra max pull to bring down height to 1
        cnn.add_module('pooling{0}'.format(4),
                       nn.MaxPool2d((3, 3), (2, 4), (0, 1))) # final size 512x2x32
        self.cnn = cnn
        self.rnn = nn.Sequential(
            BidirectionalLSTM(512, nh, nh),
            BidirectionalLSTM(nh, nh, nclass))

    def forward(self, input):
        # conv features
        conv = self.cnn(input)
        b, c, h, w = conv.size()
        # assert h == 1, "the height of conv must be 1"
        # print('size before squeeze')
        # print(conv.size())
        conv = conv.squeeze(2)
        # print('size after squeeze')
        # print(conv.size())
        conv = conv.permute(2, 0, 1)  # [w, b, c]

        # rnn features
        output = self.rnn(conv)
        # print("from model {}".format(output))
        return output
```

And following is my main :

```
from data_preparation.dataloader import DataSetOCR
from utills.dataloader_services import *
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import parameters
from models import crnn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torch.nn import CTCLoss
from utills.string_label_converter import averager, StrLabelConverter
import torch.nn.functional as F

train_dataset = DataSetOCR(
    csv_file_path= parameters.train_csv_path,
    text_file_path= parameters.text_file_path,
    root_directory= parameters.train_root)
assert train_dataset

test_dataset = DataSetOCR(
    csv_file_path= parameters.test_csv_path,
    text_file_path= parameters.text_file_path,
    root_directory= parameters.test_root)
assert test_dataset

dataloader_params = {
    'batch_size': 2,
    'shuffle': True,
    'collate_fn': my_collate

}

train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, **dataloader_params)
train_iter = iter(train_loader)

# custom weights initialization called on crnn
def weights_init(m):
    classname = m.__class__.__name__
    if classname.find('Conv') != -1:
        m.weight.data.normal_(0.0, 0.02)
    elif classname.find('BatchNorm') != -1:
        m.weight.data.normal_(1.0, 0.02)
        m.bias.data.fill_(0)


crnn = crnn.CRNN(parameters.max_image_height, 3, parameters.number_of_classes, 256)
crnn.apply(weights_init)
criterion = CTCLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(crnn.parameters(), lr=0.001)
loss_avg = averager()

image = torch.FloatTensor(2, 3, parameters.max_image_width, parameters.max_image_height)
text = torch.LongTensor(2 * 5)
length = torch.LongTensor(2)


string_converter = StrLabelConverter()
# string_converter.convert_integer_to_string()

def val(net, dataset, criterion, max_iter=100):
    print('Start val')

    for p in crnn.parameters():
        p.requires_grad = False

    net.eval()
    data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        dataset, shuffle=True, batch_size=2, collate_fn=my_collate)
    val_iter = iter(data_loader)

    i = 0
    n_correct = 0
    loss_avg = averager()

    max_iter = min(max_iter, len(data_loader))
    # print('length of dataloader')
    # print(len(data_loader))
    for i in range(max_iter):
        data = val_iter.next()
        i += 1
        images, texts = data
        batch_size = images.size(0)
        # print(images)
        # print(image)
        loadData(image, images)
        t, l = string_converter.convert_string_to_integer(texts, [])
        loadData(text, t)
        loadData(length, l)
        # print('actual label')
        # print(text)
        # print(text.size())


        # print('input from val')
        # print(i)
        print(image)
        preds = crnn(image)
        preds = F.log_softmax(preds, 2)
        print(preds)
        preds_size = Variable(torch.IntTensor([preds.size(0)] * batch_size))
        # print('predictions')
        # print(preds.size())
        cost = criterion(preds, text, preds_size, length) / batch_size
        print('validation {}'.format(cost))
        loss_avg.add(cost)

        # print('predictions before max')
        # print(preds.size())
        _, preds = preds.max(2)
        # print('after max function')
        # print(preds)
        # print(preds.size())
        preds = preds.squeeze(1) # originial 2
        # print('after squeeze')
        # print(preds.size())
        preds = preds.transpose(1, 0).contiguous().view(-1)
        # print('after transpose')
        # print(preds.size())
        sim_preds = string_converter.convert_integer_to_string(preds.data, preds_size.data)

        cpu_texts = string_converter.convert_integer_to_string(text, length)

        # for pred, target in zip(sim_preds, cpu_texts):
        #     # if pred == target:
        #     #     n_correct += 1
        #     print((pred, target))
    #
    # raw_preds = string_converter.convert_integer_to_string(preds.data, preds_size.data)[:2]
    # for raw_pred, pred, gt in zip(raw_preds, sim_preds, cpu_texts):
    #     print('%-20s => %-20s, gt: %-20s' % (raw_pred, pred, gt))
    #
    # accuracy = n_correct / float(max_iter * 100)
    # print('Test loss: %f, accuray: %f' % (loss_avg.val(), accuracy))

def trainBatch(train_iter, criterion, optimizer):
    try:
        data = train_iter.next()
    except StopIteration:
        train_iter = iter(train_loader)
        data = train_iter.next()

    images,texts = data
    loadData(image,images)
    t,l =string_converter.convert_string_to_integer(texts, [])
    loadData(text, t)
    loadData(length,l)
    batch_size = dataloader_params['batch_size']
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    # # test_util.loadData(image, data['image'])
    # text = Variable(data['integer_sequence_label'])
    # print("from train {}".format(image))
    preds = crnn(image)
    preds = F.log_softmax(preds, 2)
    preds_size = Variable(torch.IntTensor([preds.size(0)] * batch_size))



    cost = criterion(preds, text, preds_size, length) / batch_size
    # print('cost from train {}'.format(cost))
    crnn.zero_grad()
    cost.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    return cost

for epoch in range(25):
    i = 0
    while i < len(train_loader):
        for p in crnn.parameters():
            p.requires_grad = True
        crnn.train()

        cost = trainBatch(train_iter, criterion, optimizer)
        loss_avg.add(cost)
        i += 1

        if i % 50 == 0:
            print('[%d/%d][%d/%d] Loss: %f' % (epoch, 25, i, len(train_loader), loss_avg.val()))
            loss_avg.reset()

        if i % 50 == 0:
            val(crnn, test_dataset, criterion)

        # #do checkpointing
        # if i % 1 == 0:
        #     torch.save(crnn.state_dict(), '{0}/netCRNN_{1}_{2}.pth'.format('/home/bjit-531/PycharmProjects/python/bangla-ocr-version-2/bangla-ocr-version-2/weights/', epoch, i))
        #
```

I am generating the images in the data set with various fonts so they have different height and width. I am padding them during data loading , so the model receives each image with size 90 x 752 . 
What am i doing wrong here? Why the model accuracy isn't improving ?

Comment: You are doing `crnn.zero_grad()`. You should do `optimizer.zero_grad()`.

Comment: @akshayk07 yeah thanks , fixed that , but the problem didn't solve . Accuracy is still 0% . Anything else that might be the reason ?

Comment: One way to debug is to use the same accuracy calculation code for a simple dataset like MNIST (you can find some notebooks online), and check if that works since you already know that the model should converge for MNIST. Basically, you have to check your accuracy calculation code.

Comment: @aulipriyapromona Did you find a solution to make your CRNN work?

Comment: @longbowking actually I was testing with a minimal data set, turns out ctc loss doesn't work well for smaller data sets . It worked when I used the whole data set ( 300000 images )